# Defining metrics when evaluating multiple values per sample

Tags: statistics, data-science, distribution, metrics, experimental-design

I have an application that executes a

> function foo() {...}

several times for each user session. There are 2 alternate algorithms that i can implement as "foo" function and my goal is to evaluate them based on execution delay using A/B testing.

The number of times foo() is called per user session is variable but will not exceed 10000. 
The range of each value is between [1 - 400] milliseconds.
Say delays values are:

```
Algo1: [ [12, 30, 20, 40, 280] , [13, 14, 15, 100, 10], [20, 40] , ... ]
Algo2: [ [1, 10, 5, 4, 150] , [14, 10, 20], [21, 33, 41, 79], ... ]
```

My question is whats the best metric to pick the winner ?

possible options

1. average from each session, and then evaluate cdf
2. median from each session and then evaluate cdf
3. anything else ?

Comment: Depends very much upon what your goal is.  Is there some performance threshold you need to meet? Are you seeking a low average?  Are you willing to trade off a bit on average performance to achieve greater consistency?  Proposals based on average or median can still yield unacceptable extremes.

Comment: @pjs the overall goal is to pick the one with lower delay. it could go 2 ways: 1) median time for the execution for each user is low . 2) or worst case time for each execution per user should be low  . I am wondering if others have dealt with a similar metric design question and how did it work for them

Answer (score 0):

One possibility which captures both mean performance and volatility (variability) is quadratic loss:  ℓ = (Y - τ)<sup>2</sup>, where Y's are the individual outcomes and τ is a desired target value (in your case zero).  Calculate the average loss across all observations for each of your algorithms, which estimates the expected loss E[ℓ], then pick the algorithm with the smallest average loss.

It's straightforward to show that under expectation E[ℓ] = (E[Y] - τ)<sup>2</sup> + σ<sup>2</sup><sub>Y</sub>.  In other words, quadratic loss has two components:

1. how far the expected value of the Y's is from your target τ; and
2. how variable the Y's are.

Low loss is achieved by being consistently close to the target.  With a target of zero, this means you're getting values that on average are close to zero and aren't subject to large discrepancies.  Either large means or large variances will inflate the loss, so minimum loss requires both aspects to perform well simultaneously.